# Django negative numbers comparison

Tags: python, django, comparison, negative-number

I have some json data that I send to an html page through python. But when I try to compare negative numbers I see that django doesn't work properly. For example I have for jsonData.5.z_score = -1.1 but in django the following comparison doesn't work. What should I do?

```
 {% if jsonData.5.z_score < -1 %}
```

views.py :

```
jsonData = "" 
try: 
  r = requests.get(link,timeout=20) 
  r.text 
  jsonData = json.loads(r.text)
except Exception,e: 
  pass 
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e: # This is the correct syntax 
  pass 

return utils.render_template('ui/index', { 'ACCOUNT_ID': account_id, 'SETTINGS': settings, 'jsonData':jsonData })
```

Comment: Please show view, which sends jsonData

Comment: jsonData = ""
    try:
       r = requests.get(link,timeout=20)
       r.text
       jsonData = json.loads(r.text)
    except Exception,e:

       pass
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:    # This is the correct syntax
       pass


 return utils.render_template('ui/index', { 'ACCOUNT_ID': account_id, 'SETTINGS': settings, 'jsonData':jsonData })

Comment: please print jsonData or r.text,if it is to big - only part which contains z_score

Comment: It is too big so I printed jsonData.5
{
    "category": "Cognitive_Aspects",
    "subcategory": "Rumination",
    "pointsSum": 5.25,
    "z_score": -1.101395430998711,
    "score": 1.75,
    "factorCognitiveClosure": false
}

Comment: negative numbers comparison works fine, try to compare -1.1 < -1 in template. Something go wrong with jsonData. Try to output it in template